# C - Global vs Local multidimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, global-variables, local-variables

When I execute this code (gcc compiled):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int table[1005][1005];
    return 0;
}
```

it stops working, but when I change it to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int table[1005][1005];

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

it works just fine.. Why is this concretely happening? Does global variables get more space to allocate? Why?

Comment: Since your program does nothing but return 0, I think you need to define what "stops working" means.

Comment: I just execute it after compile it, that's all. It seems that it can't allocate the multidimensional-array when it is inside main. @Daniel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a large local array crash
my program?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/22945647/why-does-a-large-local-array-crash-my-program)

Comment: the stack is only so big.  Most likely that 1005*1005*sizeof(int) is exceeding the available stack size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First way is probably creating the array on the stack, the second is probably putting it into the "data segment".

The amount allocated may be too big for the stack depending on your platform.