# How to use fscanf here to write into variable from file?

Tags: c, stream, segmentation-fault, scanf

I'm trying to read a file "data.txt" with a single line "00:612:33188" (each number represents a field of data, "changes:size:permission"), and write that information into a struct. I want to write the code in general for any number of characters in those fields.

My question is regarding the use of fscanf. I cannot seem to make it work. The following code produces a segmentation fault error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXHITS 50
#define FIELDMAX 100
#define TOTALELEMENTS 100000

typedef struct Elements{
  char changes[FIELDMAX];
  char size[FIELDMAX];
  char permission[FIELDMAX];
} Elements;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  if(argc < 2) {
       printf("\nSyntax: fscanf data\n\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  Elements total[TOTALELEMENTS];
  Elements hits[MAXHITS];
  int total_elements = 0;
  int total_hits = 0;
  FILE *fp;

  // open the file and scan each field copying to the corresponding struct
  fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");

  if (fp){

    fscanf(fp,"%99s:%99s:%99s", total[total_elements].changes,
    total[total_elements].size, total[total_elements].permission);

    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", total[total_elements].changes,
    total[total_elements].size, total[total_elements].permission);

    fclose (fp);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the 99's for?

Comment: The reason for `SIGSEGV` is very likely this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22945807/50617

Comment: @nicomp Because of how I thought fscanf worked. FIELDMAX is 100, I thought in the 100th place fscan would write a '\0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely culprit of the segfault is the huge local variable  `total`

```
#define MAXHITS 50
#define FIELDMAX 100
#define TOTALELEMENTS 100000

typedef struct Elements{
  char changes[FIELDMAX];
  char size[FIELDMAX];
  char permission[FIELDMAX];
} Elements;

int main () {
...
  Elements total[TOTALELEMENTS];
}
```

100000 * 300 bytes. You get call stack overflow. 
If you reduce the TOTALELEMENTS to, say, 100,  your code works file with my test.

Answer (score 3):

The `"%s"` format reads **space delimited** strings. If there's no space, it will greedily read as much as it could.

In your case it means that the whole line will be in the `changes` field, leaving the remaining members uninitialized.

For non-space delimited records you could read the whole line into a string, and then [tokenize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) on the separator.

Comment: Or read as numeric data, then the `:` would work. You can always convert back to 0-padded strings if wanted.